# Gestures: Tip Tap and three/four finger click

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch, gestures

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop and a big fan on gestures on the trackpad. Sadly ubuntu doesn't support a lot of them by default. But I would love to have support for many more gestures like "tip tap" and three or four finger clicks.

I do currently use libinput-gestures and like this tool and customized it. But I think there is more potential in gestures which is why I would love to use even more.

So I thought I could easily read myself into the code and extend libinput-gestures on my own. I did so and realized quite fast, that libinput-gestures is just reading the output of libinput and uses then it's config file to map the read output stream to key pressing or other actions. Sadly libinput doesn't suppport those gestures so doesn't libinput-gestures.

So if I want to start somewhere I would have to start with libinput and add tracking of tip tap gestures and clicks with three and four fingers (they are just mapped to mouse button clicks so they can't be detected in the output). Sadly I am not that good in C which is why I am looking for another way.

Is there already a solution for my desired gestures on ubuntu? Or is there a way to access the trackpad directly in python? Or can you think of any other solution I haven't thought yet about.

Comment: [according to libinput](https://people.freedesktop.org/~whot/libinput-rtd/tapping.html#tap-to-click-behaviour), they do not support four-finger taps

Answer (score 1):

There is a ruby based project called fusuma (https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma) that is the closest I got to the macbook trackpad functionalities.

It's not perfect, but it's fairly good.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Sadly I can't see any difference to libinput-gestures since it has exactly the same gestures and actions (which isn't a suprise since it's also based on libinput and xdotool).

Answer (score 0):

I remember having up to 5 finger taps working with touchegg under kubuntu 16.04.
but now it does not longer work, i even made a custom version of touchegg that allowed for 3 finger scrolling to call repeated keypresses (e.g. to adjust volume)

touchegg used to get the hardware input from some library called geis (libgeis-dev), I'm not sure what exactly is no longer working, but since there haven't been any updates there for a while, it might be etter to get libinput to support it.

A little grepping on the libinput sourcecode reveals that at least some thought was given into supporting four finger taps:  BTN_TOOL_QUADTAP,
even a five one is mentioned